# Tango color frames not of best quality, looks like up-scaled from lower resolution. Is it a Tango hardware limitation?

Tags: google-project-tango

I obtain color frames from TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR. Frames are not of the best quality - looks like they are up-scaled from lower resolution.
This can be easily seen by comparing video quality from standard Android Camera app and "Project Tango Native Augmented Reality" sample app, running on the same device. 
Questions: is it what intended to be? If so then why? 
Is there a way to improve quality, of if there is a plan to improve quality in future Tango releases?

I set config_color_iso to 400, default exposition time. 
Each depth frame has corresponding color frame with the exactly same timestamp. Infrared illumination (artefacts) are seen at just a very few color frames.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to stick with the images coming out of Tango
1) If you snag another camera, or grab the camera directly, then Tango depth information stops coming.
2) More importantly to my eyes, it is the images from Tango that are the source of the point cloud - anything you want to do with coloring cloud points and surfaces and having the faintest hope of success would do better with these images
3) Trying to offload the image stream in real time requires JPEG compression if you're going straight to the cloud - raw images from tango are 1280x720, so they way in at about a megabyte each before compression

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But let me clarify the question. I get color images using C API via callback TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable(TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR,...)

Comment: ... depth frames are obtained in the same time via another callback. Color frames really come 30 fps, 1280x720 (~YV12). I do save raw color image without any compression. The problem is that quality of saved raw 1280x720 color image is substantially worse, than quality of color image 1280x720 obtained by Android Camera app, when Tango service is off. Compare video quality from standard Android Camera app and "Project Tango Native Augmented Reality" sample app. Is it a Tango hardware limitation?

Comment: Good question -  I don't know - I get images exactly the same way you do - my only concern is that if I want to texture the point clouds, I think I need those images specifically, even if not a single one of their timestamps directly lines up with a pose timestamp  :-(

Comment: Yes, we are on the same line - color images are needed for texturing. Timestamps seem not the biggest challenge. I do not see a way to get high-quality color images and depth data in the same time. If I would use Android camera API to get high-quality color images, Tango depth simply would not work. But if I use Tango API to get color images, quality is much worst. Tango developers, could you tell us, is there a plan to improve it in future?